# How to dynamically generate new data.frames for specified conditions

Tags: r, function, subset, data-manipulation

I have a large data.frame that I would like to subset by a variable ID. The data.frame is 100,000 rows long. There are 100 ID values.

Is there any straight forward way of writing a function that will create unique data.frame subsets for all ID values?

I know how to do it one by one. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
subset1 <- select(filter(data.frame, ID == 1), c(Column1, Column2))
```

I do not want to manually change the value of the ID to create 100 new subsets. Is there a way I can create a function to implement something like this:

```
subset_IDNum <- select(filter(data.frame, ID == Num), c(Column1, Column2))
```

So that it dynamically generates new subsets: subset_1, subset_2, etc. for all ID values?

Comment: Just do `split(data.frame, data.frame$ID)` in to a list which is more efficient instead of creating multiple objects in the global space

Comment: Alternatively, `by`: `by(data.frame, data.frame$ID, function(df) df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 - Write a `for` loop: Suppose you want subset_IDNum to be created separately.

```
for (i in unique(df$ID)) {
  assign(paste0("subset_ID", i),
         select(filter(df, ID == i), c(Column1, Column2)))
}
```

Retrieve the data frame of ID 1 by calling `subset_ID1`.

---

Solution 2 - Use `split`: Suppose you want a list to gather all subsets (usually it is more efficient).

```
subset_IDs <- split(df, df$ID)
```

Retrieve the data frame of ID 1 by calling `subset_IDs$"1"`.

Comment: Thank you @ytu. Follow up question, I want to add a column to each data.frame in the list based on a calculated expression. How would I add this: NewColumn <- CalculatedField / ExistingColumn

Comment: Use `transform` in `by` (similar to `split` but can pass each subset df into fct): `subset_IDs <- by(df, df$ID, function(d) transform(d, NewColumn = CalculatedField / ExistingColumn))`